# Estimate average monthly usage cost on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image]

I'm running a small app on EC2. I'm approaching the end of my free tier year. I'm interested in estimating my monthly costs to continue on with the service under the current workload. What's the best approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, analyse your existing data on the number of seconds of ec2 time used and other billable items

Next, use this tool http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html to get an estimate

Comment: How do you get the number of seconds? Right Now my instance is running 24/7 using the free tier. I'm adding a screenshot above

Comment: if your instance is running 24/7, that's about 720 hours per month. Put that in the calculator.

Comment: Hi Thank you for looking at this. My app is a proxy and requests are made on it only periodically, so although it is available 24/7 , its actually only in use less than 1% of that. I've been reading through http://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Pricing_Overview.pdf but its not clear to me whether this would be a good value given these factors

Comment: depending on what your proxy does you might be able to use something else, like AWS lambda